# Replace wrong values in df2 with true values in df1 by using 2 common columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

I have 2 data frames like this

```
TEAM <- c("PE","PE","MPI","TDT","HPT")
EmpID <- c (444452,444456,16822,339862,14828)    
ManagerID <- c(11499,11599,11899,11339,11559)
CODE <- c("F",NA,"A","H","G")
df1 <- data.frame(TEAM,EmpID,ManagerID,CODE)

TEAM <- c("MPI","TDT","HPT","PE","TDT","PE","MPI","TDT","HPT","PE")
EmpID <- c(444452,444452,444452,339862,339862,16822,339862,16822,14828,14828)
ManagerID <- c(11499,11499,11499,11339,11339,11899,11339,11899,11559,11559)
CODE <- c("A234","H665","G654","F616","H626","F234","H695","G954","G616",NA)
df2 <- data.frame(TEAM,EmpID,ManagerID,CODE)
```

I am trying to update the wrong values of ManagerID & EmpID in df2 with the true values of ManagerID & EmpID in df1 only when the TEAM & the CODE (matching the letter in CODE column in df1 with the first letter of CODE column in df2). If the team matches but the code is not correct, then the wrong values stay and shouldn't be replaced with the values from df1.

**My desired output is**

```
   TEAM  EmpID ManagerID CODE
1   MPI  16822     11899 A234
2   TDT 339862     11339 H665
3   HPT  14828     11559 G654
4    PE 444452     11499 F616
5   TDT 339862     11339 H626
6    PE 444452     11499 F234
7   MPI 339862     11339 H695
8   TDT  16822     11899 G954
9   HPT  14828     11559 G616
10   PE 444452     11599 <NA>
```

You can see that the row 7 & 8 remain unchanged since the codes don't match.

I tried doing it this way with the help from Gregor for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131770/update-a-column-in-df2-by-matching-patterns-in-columns-in-df1-df2-using-r)

```
df2$ManagerID = df1$ManagerID[match(substr(df2$CODE, 1, 1), df1$CODE)]
df2$EmpID = df1$EmpID [match(substr(df2$CODE, 1, 1), df1$CODE)]
```

I am not sure if I am headed in the right direction. Kindly help me with inputs on how efficiently to solve this.

Comment: Edited :-) Thanks Frank

Comment: I'm a little confused by your desired output. The `CODE` column in `df1` should make it so that only one row in `df2` is changed (the one with `<NA>` in `CODE`). How are the other rows being changed if they don't have matching `CODE` ?

Comment: I have mentioned there that the letter in CODE in df1 should match the first letter in CODE in df2.

Comment: Fyi, my approach does not work, probably because your CODE is a factor instead of char... not sure though.

Comment: @Frank, I converted it to char but it still din't work. I am checking what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing text subsetting here, I would initialize as character vectors, not factors:

```
df1 <- data.frame(TEAM,EmpID,ManagerID,CODE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(TEAM,EmpID,ManagerID,CODE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would then use data table (not necessary, but cleaner):

```
library(data.table)

# convert data frames to data.table
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
```

You want to create a column with the value to merge here, just taking the first character of df2's `CODE`

```
df2[ , C_SHORT := substr(CODE,1,1)]
```

We then merge the two data frames on the `TEAM/CODE` combination. This creates `NA`s where any matches do not exist. Then, test if any of the columns are `NA`, and insert the initial value if they are

```
merge(x = df2,y = df1, by.x = c("TEAM","C_SHORT"), by.y = c("TEAM","CODE"), all.x = TRUE)[
  ,
  .(
    TEAM,
    EmpID = ifelse(is.na(EmpID.y), EmpID.x, EmpID.y), 
    ManagerID = ifelse(is.na(ManagerID.y), ManagerID.x, ManagerID.y),
    CODE
  )
  ]
    TEAM  EmpID ManagerID CODE
 1:  HPT  14828     11559 G654
 2:  HPT  14828     11559 G616
 3:  MPI  16822     11899 A234
 4:  MPI 339862     11339 H695
 5:   PE 444456     11599   NA
 6:   PE 444452     11499 F616
 7:   PE 444452     11499 F234
 8:  TDT  16822     11899 G954
 9:  TDT 339862     11339 H665
10:  TDT 339862     11339 H626
```

One note: You are using `NA` here as a lookup here. This works in the merge function (which I did not realize), but IMO this is bad practice (`NA` in R really refers to missing data, whereas here it encodes something). I would think about changing how this is represented in your data.